# How to check if I can remove index from DB in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

After large redesigning of DB I need to remove all indices from it, and set new indices.
I found good scrpipt to get all indices and remove but I have problem - I cannot remove indices created by PRIMARY KEY constraint. (maybe there are also other kind of indices that I cannot remove).

My question is: how to change code below to remove all indices except indices created for primary keys or other that I cannot remove manually.

```
DECLARE @indexName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)

DECLARE [indexes] CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  [sysindexes].[name] AS [Index], [sysobjects].[name] AS [Table]
    FROM [sysindexes]
    INNER JOIN [sysobjects] ON [sysindexes].[id] = [sysobjects].[id]    
    WHERE [sysindexes].[name] IS NOT NULL AND [sysobjects].[type] = 'U'

OPEN [indexes]

FETCH NEXT FROM [indexes] INTO @indexName, @tableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC ('DROP INDEX [' + @indexName + '] ON [' + @tableName + ']')
    FETCH NEXT FROM [indexes] INTO @indexName, @tableName
END

CLOSE [indexes]
DEALLOCATE [indexes]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Marc_s answer I found correct version of script:

```
SELECT 'DROP INDEX ' + name + ' ON ' + object_name(object_id)
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE is_primary_key = 0 AND is_unique_constraint = 0
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0     -- exclude system-level tables
AND name IS NOT NULL
```

Checking if object_Id is greater than 255 isn't sufficient:
 - we had to use OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0, because some system tables like queue_messages have very high id
 - also we have to check if index is created by unique constraint : is_unique_constraint = 0

After those improvements it'll remove all indices created by user.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use the `sys.indexes` catalog view instead of the deprecated `sysindexes`.

That catalog view has a column call `is_primary_key`, so you should be able to find all non-primary key indices like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE is_primary_key = 0
```

You can easily create your DROP INDEX statements from this:

```
SELECT 'DROP INDEX ' + name + ' ON ' + object_name(object_id)
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE is_primary_key = 0
AND object_ID > 255     -- exclude system-level tables with object_id <= 255
AND name IS NOT NULL    -- exclude heaps with a NULL index name
```

Just copy&paste the output of this statement, and run that - and you should be done.

Comment: It is good advice to use that table, thanks - but it is risky to run code generated by it - it'll remove also indices from systables and returns null for HEAP type of index - code from my example returns only indices for custom tables

Comment: IF you add `AND object_ID > 255 AND name IS NOT NULL` to that statement, you get the same result; all "system-level" tables (id < 255) are excluded, as are heaps (where index name IS NULL)

Comment: ok, thanks - that's much better. Now there are my indices and few indices like: "queue_clustered_index" - do you know what it is?

Comment: @Korn - Marek K. sorry, I don't know or have your database - I cannot tell you what those are..... the DROP INDEX statement should list what table that index is defined on - check out that table....